# Slow compile times when Visual Studio 2012 is open

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Afternoon all,

I have a very strange problem. When VS 2012 is open, compile times are very slow. This slow compile time is present when building via VS and/or directly via csc.exe from the command line.

To test: Create a folder with the following items:

A batch file (compile.bat) containing:

```
echo %time%
csc /target:library class1.cs
echo %time%
```

and a class1.cs containing:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
    }
}
```

Now open a visual studio command prompt. Navigate to the above folder and run the batch command, without VS open. On my machine, this takes approximately 10ms, perfect.

I now open VS 2012, open no solution, do nothing other than open the the application so that devenv is running.

Now repeat the test by running the batch file, compile time is now 10000ms (10 seconds).

I have checked the event viewer for anything that is happening when VS is open but not when it's closed, used procmon and filemon to look for file access and checked to see if VS is enabling any services when it is open, all without success/impact.

I have even tried uninstalling and reinstalling VS, this solved the problem for the first few builds but it then reoccurred. Restarting the machine has no effect. I have no plugins installed in VS.

My colleagues machines do not display this problem and they have the same setup. This is all running on a machine with 16gb ram, 64-bit win 7 and SSD.

Anyone got any clues?

Comment: Personally I have experienced the same issue, and many other annoying issues with 2012.  I contacted Microsoft back when it was still in RC mode and was told to put a bug report in...  Guess ill have to wait for sp1 to fix the issues :(

Comment: During the slow compile with VS open, is your machine CPU limited (hard to believe) or disk-bound (more likely, but still hard to believe with an SSD)? More likely VS is trying to enforce some signing or certificates which will take time, something that csc.exe will not do.

Comment: Invoking CSC directly via the command line, with VS open, still involves the time penalty though. I have an 8 core i7 with 16gb RAM and an SSD. With no other programs running (that I've started), other than VS, I get the delay so I'd be amazed if it was a resource constraint issue!

Comment: --> http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've figured this out. I believe it was the result of some malware. I diagnosed the problem with the following steps.

1. Download ProcMon (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)
2. Add a filter to ProcMon on process name: csc.exe
3. I then ran a compile from the command line, with visual studio open. It took around 10 seconds, way too long! Looking at the output in the ProcMon window, I noticed what appeared to be csc.exe pausing for 5 secs, once towards the beginning of the trace, and once towards the end. See the following screens:

Start:

[image: Start]

End:

[image: End]

It appeared that a RegCloseKey to HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\5c28f8fbc6fe942 was causing csc.exe to wait for 5 seconds, twice.

RegKey:

[image: RegKey]

I then decided to rename this entry (added _old to the end), I then recompiled....BINGO, it compiled in less than 30ms!

After studying the entries contained in this key and some googleing it turned out that this reg key was the result of some malware. I used the following guide to remove thte malware and now the problem is completely solved.

http://www.explosiveknowledge.net/main/2012/08/19/browsemngr/

Please be aware that the guide above doesn't contain the correct reg entries, I think the virus must have been tweaked at somepoint, I couldn't find the reg entries mentioned in the guide but simply deleted the ones I'd found.

Please note that the 5c28f8fbc6fe942 part of the reg key seems to be randomly generated. If you have this problem is might be different but the values contain within will still talk about "Browser Manager".

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 2):

To understand your query we need to look into the concept of response file.

A **response file** is a text file that contains a set of compiler commandline
switches. When you execute CSC.exe, the compiler opens response files and uses any
switches that are specified in them as though the switches were passed to CSC.exe on the
command line. You instruct the compiler to use a response file by specifying its name on the command line prepended by an @ sign. For example, you could have a response file called
MyProject.rsp that contains the following text:

/out:MyProject.exe
/target:winexe

To cause CSC.exe to use these settings, you’d invoke it as follows:

**csc.exe @MyProject.rsp CodeFile1.cs CodeFile2.cs**

This tells the C# compiler what to name the output file and what kind of target to create. As you can see, response files are very convenient because you don’t have to manually express the desired command-line arguments each time you want to compile your project.

When you install the .NET Framework, it installs a default global CSC.rsp file in the
%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\vX.X.Xdirectory (where X.X.X is the version of
the .NET Framework you have installed).

**The Visual studio 2012 uses this default response file for compiling the code.
Because the global CSC.rsp file references all of the assemblies.Referencing all of these assemblies could slow the compiler down a bit.**

Comment: Thanks very much for this detailed response but the problem appears to be intermittent, I will check the response file and see if any of the dependencies to see if I can understand why this might be.

Comment: I've had another look into this, as the problem still happens intermittently. To my understanding, the CSC.rsp file will be used regardless of whether I invoke the compile via the CLI or VS, which means for this to be the explanation, VS must be locking/using one of these dlls in some way that slows down CSC. The next time the problem happens I'll get FileMon open and see if I can see which one , if any, of these dlls is causing the problem.